# My sister will sponsor her place for my stay in UK,what should my sister show of proof for my UK Visa?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, tourist-visas

I am currently applying for a UK Visa and my sister has been working there for 2 years now.

She said she will sponsor my STAY ONLY in her rented house.

I will be the one to buy the plane ticket and cover all expenses once I get there.

What proof should she send to me for my UK Visa?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to telling what she will be providing you with, you must document that your sister is *legally* resident in the UK.

Also, since she lives in rented accommodation, she must show that her landlord is okay with her boarding guests -- either in the form of a lease that explicitly allows this in general, or a letter from the landlord that permits it.

It's also a good idea to document your relationship, e.g. with birth certificates showing you have the same parents.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean what she should write in her letter of sponsorship, which will become part of the visa application.

The letter should reflect what she is willing to sponsor

- accommodation in her home
- timeframe

The reader should, as a result, understand what she is willing to sponsor and what not

- not to sponser expenses

  - with you proving that you can pay those expenses